# Javascript Array.find() has problems with sparse arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Javascript has some nice functions like .map, .filter, etc.

These work great, no matter if your array is sparse or not. They fire their callbackfn once per item in the array. Excellent.

There are now also .find and .findIndex function, however these work differently. They fire their predicate once per INDEX in the array. This is completely incorrect behaviour when used with sparse arrays.

For example, if you have an array that has a range of 1000 - 1100, your predicate will be run 1000 times passing in undefined as the input param, before finally getting to your actual data.

I feel like...
a) all of these functions should work in a similar way (.map and .filter have it right, while .find and .findIndex are doing it wrong)
b) this is a bug, and should be fixed

Thoughts?

Comment: well this definitely ain't the place to discuss it.

Comment: Well `map` have no use of undefined values that's why it skips them. But `find` and `findIndex` could be used to find the undefined indexes in the array so it doesn't skip anything!

Comment: `find` and `findIndex` are simple function. You can make your own in two minutes.

Comment: What do you expect `array.find(x => x === undefined)` to do? How could the engine find a match unless it looks at all values? The match function might also involve the index (second argument to the callback).

Comment: both [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) both state in their descriptions: "callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values." so I would consider this a bug with `find`

Comment: @CrayonViolent—MDN is not an authority and seems to be wrong about that. [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.find) is the authority and it appears to specify that the callback (for *find*) is called for every index from 0 to length - 1.

Comment: @RobG http://i.imgur.com/3eue6GG.gif okay you got me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for "thoughts" about why a particular language feature was specified as it was.

Comment: @CrayonViolent— [*fixerated*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). ;-)

Comment: Well, it was still very helpful to me - I may have posed my question the wrong way, but I did get what I was after in the end! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior is as per specification. Looking at the current specification draft, comparing, e.g.:

- The specification for [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.filter) tests for the presence of the value before processing (step 8c):

  > 8. Repeat, while `k < len`
  >      a. Let `Pk` be ! `ToString(k)`.
  >      b. Let `kPresent` be ? `HasProperty(O, Pk)`.
  >      c. If `kPresent` is true, then *[...]*
- The specification for [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find) does not test for the presence of the value before processing:

  > 6. Repeat, while `k < len`
  >      a. Let `Pk` be ! `ToString(k)`.
  >      b. Let `kValue` be ? `Get(O, Pk)`.
  >      c. *[...]*

So, as you state, the behavior is indeed different, and it's different by specification.

As to the design considerations that went into this, I can only guess at this point, but if you feel that this is a bug, you can file a bug report [here](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262#ecmascript).

---

**Update**

It seems that the original specification draft of the [`find()`](https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/5079436) and [`findIndex()`](https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/5079427) methods did indeed have array hole checking/skipping implemented. These drafts were, according to the meeting minutes, proposed at the [March 14th 2013 ECMA Technical Committee 39 meeting](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es6/2013-03/mar-14.md).

In August 2014, a [bug](https://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3107) was raised, arguing that array holes should be treated as `undefined` rather than skipping them.

> `Array#find` and `Array#findIndex` should treat holes as `undefined`
>   rather than skipping them, for consistency with the recent trend in
>   TC39 to treat holes as `undefined`.

The issue seems to have propped up in a [discussion about the proposed behavior for `Array.prototype.includes()`](https://github.com/tc39/Array.prototype.includes/issues/15) revolving around the question of whether

```
[,,,].includes(undefined)
```

should return true or false.

Also in this discussion, it is stated that *[...] The recent trend in TC39 has been to treat holes as undefined.*

Hole checking for the `find()` and `findIndex()` methods was subsequently removed in [revision 27](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2014-August/039038.html) of the ECMAScript 6 Draft.

Reading through the linked resources, you can get a more complete view on what led to removing the hole checking/skipping from the `find()` and `findIndex()` specification, but the general consensus at the time seemed to be *"holes: nobody wants them"*.

Comment: I think the OP is suggesting that the methods have been implemented as per the specification, but that the specification should have been different in the first place.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm aware of this. Thought it'd be helpful to have the relevant parts of the specification here since they're not mentioned in the question. Will continue trying to find information about the design considerations that went into this.

Comment: @nnnnnn I've updated my answer. I think I've been able to find sufficient resources that illustrate how the currently specified behavior came to be.

Comment: Thank you @RobbyCornelissen :)

Yes, mainly I was confused about the inconsistency between the different functions - to me, they should all be the same (whatever that may be).